# Is it possible to make the shutter speed slower than 30 seconds on the Canon 4000D?

Tags: canon, long-exposure, shutter-speed

I have a Canon 4000D and I would like to take some long exposure photography. It only allows shutter speeds up to 30 seconds and I would prefer to have the ability to take shots that are exposed for 1 minute or more. Is it possible? I'm OK with using 3rd party software like CHDK if I have to.

Comment: Have you looked at MagicLantern? Are you opposed to the simple method: a remote shutter release? There are simple models that simply lock the button down and fancier ones where the exposure is set in the release.

Comment: Slightly different camera model, same question and same answer.

Comment: @MichaelC Maybe the other question can be modified to cover both, now it is not the same question.

Comment: @Orbit How do the two questions differ?

Comment: @MichaelC Because it is about a different camera model, and people may not know the answer is the same. But I just learned that most duplicates won't be deleted, so nevermind.

Comment: They are dIfferent camera models that are identical in all respects that are applicable to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to select exposure times longer than 30 seconds on most DSLR's.

If you want an exposure time longer than 30 seconds, you have to use "Bulb" mode. You set the camera to bulb mode, and hold the shutter button as long as you want your exposure to be. Because this is not very convenient, most people use a remote control to open and close the shutter. This can be a wired remote, a wireless remote control or a telephone app(although one could say that that is also a wireless remote).

Comment: You can get a IR remote for most Canon models for $10-$30.

Comment: You can get a wired remote that works much better for most use cases for about $5. You can get a wired remote with built-in intervalometer for $15.

Comment: Cheap Chinese IR remotes for 5 dollar also seem to work just fine ;) I think the 4000D also has wifi built in. Maybe a free Canon app will do the trick too.

Comment: An IR remote is not unlikely to drain its battery real quick if used that way ... and stray infrared can be a problem with long exposures.

Comment: @rackandboneman I always use an IR remote. I press once to open the shutter, and once to close. I use Nikon though, no idea how it works on other brands.

Comment: @Orbit IR remotes don't work so well if you want to do [automatic continuous bursts](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/45909/15871) , if you want to [stand well behind the camera](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/40251/15871) in an environment that does not allow the IR signal to bounce off walls or mirrors to reach the front of the camera in sufficient strength to be detected by the camera, you want to use mirror lockup, or you want to do a shutter button half-press with the remote.

Comment: @Orbit IR remotes don't work at all with Canon EOS 1-series cameras, since they have no IR receiver.

Comment: @MichaelC I suppose it depends on the camera and personal preference. I like IR because it is about the size of a post stamp, so it it always in my bag. I don't have any problem with reception because my camera has a second receiver at the back. I generally love wires, because they never run out of battery, but since I don't use it very often, IR works for me. It's nice to have it when I need it.