# Canon 60d Wireless Remote

Tags: canon-60d, wireless

I am looking at getting a wireless remote as a Christmas gift for my wife.  She has a Canon 60d.  Would this remote work for her ?  Any help would be greatly appreciated, photography is totally not my thing.

http://www.target.com/p/merkury-flickerfree-camera-remote-control/-/A-15410614

Comment: Difficult to say as it is a generic Remote - This one will as I use one and it works just fine -http://www.amazon.com/Canon-RC-6-Wireless-Controller-Digital/dp/B0037NX6JY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1419262961&sr=8-1&keywords=rc-6

Comment: IMHO a wired remote release is preferable to a wireless. The following link is to an answer that outlines why. And if you want to hear the other side of the coin, read Robin's comments below the answer.    http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/40251/15871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have that, but it was more like $2. Look on ebay and aliexpress for Chinese sellers. In fact, I had bought a wored remote and they were *so* cheap that I got this as a no brainer.

On the 60D, the only button that does anything is the shutter.  You can't pre-focus either, like you can even with a wired remote by holding the button half way. I looked into it and that's Canon's communication protocol: **none of these genuine or aftermarket versions can do that**.

It can be handy for including yourself in the shot, if you focus first and then take it off autofocus. Pressing the trigger can be handier than setting the timer. For use as "don't touch the camera" to make for a more stable shot, I don't like it because of the lack of half-press, and I don't use it.

Comment: Thx @jdlugosz.  Do you know if the one in the amazon link above allows for the pre-focus half press?  If not can you recommend one that does?

Comment: The IR protocol does not have a half-press, so no conrroller can do so.

Comment: To use half press functionality, you need a wired remote, which allows you to use the camera exactly as you would by pressing the shutter button.